# Can someone please help with the proof of this?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free

Given an unambiguous context-free language L and an unambiguous regular language L (moreover, every regular language is unambiguous) such that L∩ R = ∅, then prove that L∪ R is also unambiguous.

Comment: We're not looking for posts that are just the text of an exercise-style task.  We're a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question about your situation - preferably one that will be useful to others who aren't looking at the exact same exercise.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take unambiguous grammars for L and R with start symbols $S_L$ and $S_R$. For L union R take a grammar that starts with $S->S_L$, $S->S_R$. Since no string is both in L and R, only one of the initial two rules can succeed, so the grammar is unambiguous.

Comment: thanks , but can you please elaborate slightly , I am not sure I am getting it.